# Como criar um select em firebird?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird, tabela-banco-de-dados

Criar um select listando 03 campos de qualquer tabela, ordenando os dados pelo 2º campo.

Sou bem fraco em firebird alguém consegue me dizer como faria isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi a sua pergunta, você quer algo assim:

```
select
  campo1,
  campo2,
  campo3
from
  tabela
order by
  2 /*ordenado pelo índice das colunas*/
```